# python with Quickbooks Online API v3

Tags: python, quickbooks-online

I need some help implementing a python app that accesses the Quickbooks API.  I have successfully written several apps that use APIs, but once we get into the OAuth world, I get a bit lost.

At any rate, I found the quickbooks-python wrapper here:
https://github.com/troolee/quickbooks-python

but there are zero examples of working code showing how to implement properly.  I imagine that a more experienced python programmer could figure out how to make this work without any instructions, but it seems like I'm missing the basics.

If I could get it connected, I could probably get it to work from there...

It seems like the documentation on github jumps around and for a more experienced programmer, would probably make perfect sense.  But I'm just not following...

```
from quickbooks import *

consumerKey =           "fromApiConsole"
consumerSecret =        "fromApiConsole"
callbackUrl =           "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3"

qbObject = QuickBooks(
        consumer_key = consumerKey,
        consumer_secret = consumerSecret,
        callback_url = callbackUrl
        )

authorize_url = qbObject.get_authorize_url() # will create a service, and further set up the qbObject.

oauth_token = request.GET['oauth_token']
oauth_verifier = request.GET['oauth_verifier']
realm_id = request.GET['realmId']

session = qbObject.get_access_tokens(oauth_verifier)

# say you want access to the reports

reportType = "ProfitAndLoss"

url = "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/asdfasdfas/"
url += "reports/%s" % reportType

r = session.request( #This is just a Rauth request
    "POST",
    url,
    header_auth = True,
    realm = realm_id,
    params={"format":"json"}
    )

qb = QuickBooks(
    consumer_key = consumerKey,
    consumer_secret = consumerSecret,
    access_token = qbtoken.access_token, # the stored token
    access_token_secret = qbtoken.access_token_secret, # the stored secret
    company_id = qbtoken.realm_id #the stored realm_id
    )

qbText = str(qb.query_objects(business_object, params, query_tail))

print qbText
```

I am pretty sure that I am:

1. importing the wrong modules/classes
2. missing huge pieces of code to "glue together" the samples found on github
3. not using django here and i know the request class above is in django, but i'd really like to just make this work as a python script without using django
4. not getting the token/identifier/realmId from the initial authorize_url function.  it prints on the screen, but i'm not sure how to grab it...

The end goal here is really just to connect and get a P&L statement from Quickbooks Online.  If I can get that far, I am sure I can get the rest of what I need out of the API.  I don't really need to CHANGE anything, I'm just looking to include data from the reports into some dashboards.

*** UPDATE ***

okay, i figured out how to get it to connect, but i'm not sure how to get to the reports.

the answer was this, which was on the prior API page:

```
Accessing the API
Once you've gotten a hold of your QuickBooks access tokens, you can create a QB object:

qb = QuickBooks(consumer_key = QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
        consumer_secret = QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        access_token = QB_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
        access_token_secret = QB_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        company_id = QB_REALM_ID
        )
```

still trying to get the basic reports...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so here's how to make this work.  I'm focused on the reports, so here's how you can get reports from Quickbooks Online API using Python:

1) Go to https://github.com/finoptimal-dev/quickbooks-python and download the code

2) Make sure you have rauth installed.  If you are on AWS/EC2, simply:

```
sudo yum install rauth
```

3) Edit the quickbooks2.py file and add the following to the END:

```
qb = QuickBooks(consumer_key = QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
        consumer_secret = QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        access_token = QB_ACCESS_TOKEN, 
        access_token_secret = QB_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        company_id = QB_REALM_ID
        )
```

4) Setup a sandbox application on the Quickbooks site here: https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/app/startcreate (you will have to create a developer account if you don't already have one)

5) Once setup, you can go to the "Keys" tab of the App and grab the App Token, OAuth Consumer Key and OAuth Consumer Secret.

6) Go to the Intuit Developer Playground at https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA and use the info from step #5 to obtain the Access Token and Access Token Secret.

7) Change the variables in Step #3 to the correct values.  For QB_REALM_ID, this is the Company ID.  You can get this in the sandbox by logging into https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/sandbox and looking for Company ID.

7) add the following code below the code from step #3 above

```
print qb.get_report('ProfitAndLoss','summarize_column_by=Month&start_date=2014-01-01&end_date=2014-12-31')
```

I use the above dates b/c the Quickbooks Sandbox company has no Income/Expense data in 2015, so you have to pick dates in 2014.

8) IMPORTANT: To use with the Quickbooks Sandbox for reporting purposes, you need to change the get_report() function to use the base_url_v3 instead of being hard-coded to the production URL.

Look for a row in the get_report() function that looks like this:

```
url = "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/%s/" % \
```

and change it to this:

```
url = self.base_url_v3 + "/company/%s/" % \
```

9) Now you can change base_url_v3 all the way at the top to this:

```
base_url_v3 =  "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3"
```

10) And now you should now be able to run:

```
python quickbooks2.py
```

You should see a bunch of JSON data from the Quickbooks Sandbox company.

11) You can explore a bit to test out the appropriate URLs here: https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Reports

12) The report reference is here: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0400_references/reports and this shows you which parameters you can use.  To test parameters in the Explorer, you enter them in the "Request Body" section.

I struggled with this for a while and finally figured it out.  Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: >obtain the Access Token and Access Token Secret.

Issue is, the token will expire one day, isn't it? I want access_token that does not expire as I myself will be using application.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with Python but someone had shared this code with me for oauth earlier.If you have additional questions on the code, I will not be able to answer them.

**NOTE: The below code also makes calls to V2 QBO apis. Please do not use that part as it is deprecated.**

See if it helps-

## Import Python

```
from rauth import OAuth1Session, OAuth1Service
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import xmltodict

class QuickBooks():
    """A wrapper class around Python's Rauth module for Quickbooks the API"""

access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
company_id = 0
callback_url = ''
session = None

base_url_v3 =  "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3"
base_url_v2 = "https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1"

request_token_url = "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token"
access_token_url = "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token"

authorize_url = "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin"

# Things needed for authentication
qbService = None

request_token = ''
request_token_secret = ''


def __init__(self, **args):

    if 'consumer_key' in args:
        self.consumer_key = args['consumer_key']

    if 'consumer_secret' in args:
        self.consumer_secret = args['consumer_secret']

    if 'access_token' in args:
        self.access_token = args['access_token']

    if 'access_token_secret' in args:
        self.access_token_secret = args['access_token_secret']

    if 'company_id' in args:
        self.company_id = args['company_id']

    if 'callback_url' in args:
        self.callback_url = args['callback_url']


def get_authorize_url(self):
    """Returns the Authorize URL as returned by QB, 
    and specified by OAuth 1.0a.
    :return URI:
    """
    self.qbService = OAuth1Service(
            name = None,
            consumer_key = self.consumer_key,
            consumer_secret = self.consumer_secret,
            request_token_url = self.request_token_url,
            access_token_url = self.access_token_url,
            authorize_url = self.authorize_url,
            base_url = None
        )
    self.request_token, self.request_token_secret = self.qbService.get_request_token(
            params={'oauth_callback':self.callback_url}
        )

    return self.qbService.get_authorize_url(self.request_token)




def get_access_tokens(self, oauth_verifier):
    """Wrapper around get_auth_session, returns session, and sets 
    access_token and access_token_secret on the QB Object.
    :param oauth_verifier: the oauth_verifier as specified by OAuth 1.0a
    """
    session = self.qbService.get_auth_session(
            self.request_token, 
            self.request_token_secret,
            data={'oauth_verifier': oauth_verifier})

    self.access_token = session.access_token
    self.access_token_secret = session.access_token_secret

    return session



def create_session(self):
    if self.consumer_secret and self.consumer_key and self.access_token_secret and self.access_token:
        # print "hi"
        session = OAuth1Session(self.consumer_key,
            self.consumer_secret,
            self.access_token,
            self.access_token_secret,
            )
        # print session
        self.session = session
    else:
        pass
        #TODO: raise an error
    return self.session


def keep_trying(self, r_type, url, header_auth, realm, payload=''):

    if self.session != None:
        session = self.session
    else:
        session = self.create_session()
        self.session = session

    trying = True
    tries = 0
    while trying:
        print url
        tries += 1
        if "v2" in url:
            r = session.request(r_type, url, header_auth, realm, data=payload)

            r_dict = xmltodict.parse(r.text)
            # print "DICT", r_dict
            if "FaultInfo" not in r_dict or tries > 4:
                trying = False
        else:
            # url = "https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/184010684/query?query=SELECT * FROM JournalEntry"
            # url = "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/184010684/journalentry/24772"
            # url = "https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/184010684/query?query='SELECT+*+FROM+JournalEntry'"
            # url = "https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/184010684/query?query=SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20JournalEntry&"
            print url, r_type
            headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
            r = session.request(r_type, url, header_auth, realm, headers = headers)
            # r.headers
            print "\n\n INITIAL TEXT \n\n", r.text


            print "request headers:", r.request.headers
            print "request URL:", r.request.url
            print "response headers:", r.headers

            r_dict = r.text
            if "Fault" not in r_dict or tries > 4:
                trying = False
            r_dict = []

    return r_dict

def fetch_customer(self, pk):

    if pk:
        url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/customer/v2/%s/%s" % ( self.company_id, pk)
        r_dict = self.keep_trying("GET", url, True, self.company_id)

        return r_dict['Customer']


def fetch_customers(self, all=False, page_num=0, limit=10):
    if self.session != None:
        session = self.session
    else:
        session = self.create_session()
        self.session = session

    # We use v2 of the API, because what the fuck, v3.
    url = self.base_url_v2
    url += "/resource/customers/v2/%s" % (self.company_id)

    customers = []

    if all:
        counter = 1
        more = True

        while more:
            payload = {
                "ResultsPerPage":30,
                "PageNum":counter,
                }

            trying = True

            # Because the QB API is so iffy, let's try until we get an non-error

            # Rewrite this to use same code as above.
            while trying:
                r = session.request("POST", url, header_auth = True, data = payload, realm = self.company_id)
                root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
                if root[1].tag != "{http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd}ErrorCode":
                    trying = False
                else:
                    print "Failed"

            session.close()
            qb_name = "{http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2}"

            for child in root:
                # print child.tag, child.text
                if child.tag == "{http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo}Count":

                    if int(child.text) < 30:
                        more = False
                        print "Found all customers"

                if child.tag == "{http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo}CdmCollections":
                    for customer in child:

                        customers += [xmltodict.parse(ET.tostring(customer))]

            counter += 1

            # more = False
            # print more

    else:

        payload = {
            "ResultsPerPage":str(limit),
            "PageNum":str(page_num),
            }

        r = session.request("POST", url, header_auth = True, data = payload, realm = self.company_id)

        root = ET.fromstring(r.text)

        #TODO: parse for all customers


    return customers

def fetch_sales_term(self, pk):
    if pk:
        url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/sales-term/v2/%s/%s" % ( self.company_id, pk)
        r_dict = self.keep_trying("GET", url, True, self.company_id)
        return r_dict


def fetch_invoices(self, **args):
    if "query" in args:
        payload = ""
        if "customer" in args['query']:
            payload = {
                "Filter":"CustomerId :Equals: %s" % (args['query']['customer'])
            }


        # while more:
        url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/invoices/v2/%s/" % (self.company_id)
        r_dict = self.keep_trying("POST", url, True, self.company_id, payload)
        invoices = r_dict['qbo:SearchResults']['qbo:CdmCollections']['Invoice']

        return invoices
    elif "pk" in args:
        # TODO: Not tested
        url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/invoice/v2/%s/%s" % ( self.company_id, args['pk'])
        r_dict = self.keep_trying("GET", url, True, self.company_id)
        return r_dict
    else:
        url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/invoices/v2/%s/" % (self.company_id)
        r_dict = self.keep_trying("POST", url, True, self.company_id, payload)
        return "BLAH"


def fetch_journal_entries(self, **args):
    """ Because of the beautiful way that journal entries are organized
    with QB, you're still going to have to filter these results for the
    actual entity you're interested in. Luckily it only returns the entries
    that are relevant to your search

    :param query: a dictionary that includes 'customer', and the QB id of the
        customer
    """

    if "query" in args:
        payload = {}
        more = True
        counter = 1
        journal_entries = []

        if "customer" in args['query']:

            payload = {
                "Filter":"CustomerId :Equals: %s" % (args['query']['customer'])
            }

            # payload = {
            #     "query":"SELECT * FROM JournalEntry",
            # }

        while more:

            payload["ResultsPerPage"] = 30

            payload["PageNum"] = counter

            # url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/journal-entries/v2/%s/" % (self.company_id)
            # url = self.base_url_v3 + "/company/%s/query" % (self.company_id)
            url = "https://qb.sbfinance.intuit.com/v3/company/184010684/query?query=SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20JournalEntry&"

            r_dict = self.keep_trying("GET", url, True, self.company_id, payload)

            more = False
            # print r_dict['qbo:SearchResults']['qbo:Count']
            counter = counter + 1
            # if int(r_dict['qbo:SearchResults']['qbo:Count']) < 30:
                # more = False

            # journal_entry_set = r_dict['qbo:SearchResults']['qbo:CdmCollections']['JournalEntry']
            # journal_entries += [journal_entry_set]
        return []
        # return r_dict['qbo:SearchResults']['qbo:CdmCollections']['JournalEntry']

    elif "pk" in args:
        # TODO: Not Tested
        url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/journal-entry/v2/%s/%s" % ( self.company_id, args['pk'])
        r_dict = self.keep_trying("GET", url, True, self.company_id)
        return r_dict
    else:
        url = self.base_url_v2 + "/resource/journal-entries/v2/%s/" % (self.company_id)
        r_dict = self.keep_trying("POST", url, True, self.company_id)
        print r_dict
        return "BLAH"
```

Comment: thanks nimisha, but i'm still not following how to use this code.  i can't really get it to "do" anything at all.  the instructions on the github page don't really tell you how to use it.  Even if you go back to the simonv3 version, it just says "Works like any Python module, but you'll need rauth."